# iOS picker view with normal and bold text labels in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, nsattributedstring

I need to have a picker view with some entries, that have normal font weight and some with bold font weight. Finding out how to create an attributed string is not the problem, so I put everything together but I couldn't see a difference. The first row is not bold and not bigger. Different colors do work, though.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let darkColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let lightColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.3)                             
    if row == 0 {
        return NSAttributedString(string: "first row bold and black", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:darkColor, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)])
    } else {
        return NSAttributedString(string: "other rows gray and normal", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:lightColor])
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a different font for your first row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the viewForRow, rather than attributedTitleForRow, and you get a lot more control

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
{
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()

    if row == 0
    {
        pickerLabel.text = "first row bold and black"
        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
    }
    else
    {
        pickerLabel.text = "other rows gray and normal"
        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    }

    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code instead ?

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"first row bold and black"];
NSRange selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);

[String beginEditing];
[String addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20] range:selectedRange];
[String endEditing];
```

Comment: This is Objective-C. I am writing with Swift, as mentioned in the title of the question.

Comment: Not Swift, but tried this for Objective-C, and it doesn't work with NSFontAttributeName. Seems like UIPickerView requires the `viewForRow:` override as shown by @Russel to get font changes. But it does work for other attributes such as NSForegroundColorAttributeName and NSBackgroundColorAttributeName.